# Find asymptotic of the next sequence : $a_n =\sqrt[4]{1}+\sqrt[4]{2}+...+\sqrt[4]{n}, n \to \infty$

Tags: analysis, proof-verification

Find asymptotic of sequence $a_n=\sqrt[4]{1}+\sqrt[4]{2}+...+\sqrt[4]{n}, n \to \infty$.

Here is my solution:

> $$\sqrt[4]{1}+\sqrt[4]{2}+...+\sqrt[4]{n}=n^\frac{5}{4}\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n} \sqrt[4]\frac{i}{n}\frac{1}{n} =n^\frac{5}{4}\left(\int\limits_{0}^{1} \sqrt[4]{x}dx+o(1)\right)=n^\frac{5}{4}\left(\frac{4}{5}+o(1)\right)$$

But  I'm not sure that it's correct. Could someone please check it and let me know what is wrong?

Comment: Looks good!  You could generalize to kth roots.

Comment: I've added the tag [tag:proof-verification] to the question.

Answer (score 1):

It is correct, and the problem can be generalized.

The sum for a general power $p$ can be expressed by the generalized harmonic number as follows

$$s_{n}(p)=\sum _{k=1}^n k^p = H_n^{(-p)}$$

The asymptotic behaviour of the harmonic number is then (for $p \ne -1$)

$$H_n^{(-p)} \to \left(\frac{n^{p+1}}{p+1}+\frac{1}{2}n^p\right)+\zeta (-p)+\frac{p}{12 n} +O(\frac{1}{n^3})$$

and for $p=-1$

$$H_n^{(1)}=H_n \to \log (n)+\gamma+\frac{1}{2 n}-\frac{1}{12 n^2}+O(\frac{1}{n^3})$$

Hence the series is divergent for $p\ge-1$ and convergent otherwise.